# itertools.cycle(['eng', 'rus']).__next__ not works properly

Tags: python

Ayo, guys
Im started to learn python 2 days ago and started with simple Translator

My problem is:
I wanted to write "@" to the console, my values change, but I don't know how to achieve that "Toggle" effect, when when writing "@" is chekcing if language number 1 is enabled and I change it to language number 2 and vice versa, if Language number 2 is enabled then switch to Language number 1

I found a solution on the Internet by:

```py
var = itertools.cycle(['1', '2']).__next__
```

However, I can't get langtoggle to give me values one by one

At the moment, I'm stuck on this moment, which gives me value number 2 and does not want to change it to value 1

Please tell me what am I doing wrong?

Thank you :)

```py
import itertools

langtoggle = itertools.cycle(['eng', 'rus']).__next__
engstroke = 'ENGLISH > RUSSIAN'
russtroke = 'RUSSIAN > ENGLISH'
lstroke = engstroke


while True:
    print (lstroke)
    word = input('Введите слово: ')
    if word == '@': 
        while True:
            langtoggle()
            if langtoggle() == 'eng':
                lstroke = engstroke
            if langtoggle() == 'rus':
                lstroke = russtroke
                break
```

to be honest, I need a solution what let me change to 1,2,3 and more values by same action so thats why I dont want to use boolean value for that problem

Also, I notice that "var()" cycling to next value even if im just checking this var in "if var() = 1"
that looks strange, but I dont understand a huge things in coding right now, so..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `while` block you're calling `langtoggle()` three times.  Change this to be called only once.

Something like this:

```
import itertools

langtoggle = itertools.cycle(['eng', 'rus']).__next__
engstroke = 'ENGLISH > RUSSIAN'
russtroke = 'RUSSIAN > ENGLISH'
lstroke = eng


while True:
    print (lstroke)
    word = input('Введите слово: ')
    if word == '@': 
        while True:
            toggled = langtoggle()
            if toggled  == 'eng':
                lstroke = engstroke
            if toggled  == 'rus':
                lstroke = russtroke
                break
```

This is your code but modified by setting `toggled` to the result of the first call to `langtoggle()`.  Then the tests are looking at the value of `toggled` instead of separate calls they were making previously.